# The Geometry of a Linear Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, svd

Consider a **square** matrix of **full rank** (these assumptions are made for the sake of simplicity).

This matrix expresses in coordinates a Linear Mapping that sends the unit sphere to a hyperellipsoid on the same space.

How we can obtain the equation of the hyperellipsoid or at least the directions of its axes?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is exactly the geometric interpretation of singular value decomposition(SVD) of a matrix. [This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition#Geometric_meaning) explains the process in detail.

Comment: Yes, and actually my question descends from my preliminary survey of svd. But let us ignore svd for a moment. There is some other way to obtain the desired equation **without** SVD?